# React Web Application Login using OpenIAM OAuth Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, pkce

We are trying to integrate react webapplication to login through OpenIAM. We are using enterprise version of OpenIAM. We have used OAuth2.0 PKCE flow. Token is issued to the application. However, Token does not seem to be JWT token, it seems to be UUID. Is there a way we can configure OpenIAM to issue JWT token so that we read claims and build User context in our application?

We have tried searching through OpenIAM documentation but we are not successful in finding any information around this requirement.